# run script after DOM is ready and also after ajax call

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have one script that runs after DOM is ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

and on same time have the same script listen and run again based on finished ajax call? Here is js code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {    
$(".youtube").each(function() {  
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(//i.ytimg.com/vi/' + this.id + '/hqdefault.jpg)');
        });
 });
```

I am opening some content using modal window, however the js code does not fire because DOM is already there. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see an ajax call anywhere in your example code. All it does is wait until the DOM is ready and then loop through all elements containing the youtube className adding a background image to each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stuff the "script" into a function:

```
function foo() {  ... do your stuff ... }

$(document).ready(function() { foo(); }); // run at document load
$.ajax({.... success: foo}); // run after ajax call returns
```